# How to use postfix to reject the spam mail with fake domain sender?

Tags: postfix

My mailbox is running postfix 2.6 in centos.
I always get spam mail as below:

```
Delivered-To: joe@ourcompany.com
Received: from outlook.com (unknown [118.219.111.157])
    by mail.ourcompany.com (Postfix) with SMTP id 47DC91E3C
    for <joe@ourcompany.com>; Fri,  1 Sep 2017 22:19:42  (UTC)
Received: from outlook.com (unknown (1.0.0.0])
     by outlook.com with SMTP id 5067aad2-a74f-47a7-8929-79dbc3db9aed;
     for <bill.gates@outlook.com>;Fri, 01 Sep 2017 22:19:38 
Message-ID: <c9dc7f4f1fbab3827c182e4b6abb7e20@outlook.com>
From: "=?utf-8?money?=" <bill.gates@outlook.com>
```

It's obvious `bill.gates@outlook.com` is fake and `118.219.111.157` is unkown.
How to use postfix itself to reject this kind of spam mail?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Take a look at [Postfix SMTP relay and access control README](http://www.postfix.org/SMTPD_ACCESS_README.html)

You could do it e.g. by [`smtpd_recipient_restrictions`](http://www.postfix.org/postconf.5.html#smtpd_recipient_restrictions). There are several tests for detecting fake and **invalid domains** and hostnames in both sender and recipient address, and `HELO` hostname:

```
smtpd_recipient_restrictions =
    . . .
    reject_invalid_hostname,
    reject_non_fqdn_sender,
    reject_unknown_sender_domain,
    reject_non_fqdn_recipient,
    reject_unknown_recipient_domain,
    . . .
```

In order to prevent **unauthorized use of existing domains**, you can use [*Sender Policy Framework*](http://www.openspf.org/Introduction) (SPF). The sending server doesn't necessarily have `PTR` matching the domain, and the domain doesn't necessarily have `A` or `MX` records for the IP address, as `MX` is for receiving mail rather than sending it. For example an ISP could handle hundreds of domains on the same MTA. SPF addresses this problem by listing permitted, neutral and forbidden sending MTAs for the domain. That's why it's exactly the test you should perform to say whether the MTA is allowed.

SPF requires external policy service. The test is added to `smtpd_recipient_restrictions` like this:

```
    check_policy_service unix:private/policy-spf,
```

HowtoForge has an excellent article on [How To Implement SPF In Postfix](https://www.howtoforge.com/postfix_spf), for continuing from this.

You used `bill.gates@outlook.com` as an example. The `outlook.com` has an SPF record, and the IP address `118.219.111.157` falls in `~all` i.e. `SOFTFAIL`. You can decide how aggressive you wan't to be about `SOFTFAIL`s, as SPF itself defines that only `-` should be directly rejected.

On the other hand the IP address spoofing sender domains may already be blacklisted on some DNS RBL, and you could decide to add some blacklists with [`reject_rbl_client`](http://www.postfix.org/postconf.5.html#reject_rbl_client). This particular IP seems to be only blacklisted in Servicesnet:

> Servicesnet, the South Korean Network Blocking List, lists Korean IP
>   Address ranges, along with older ARIN ranges that have been identified
>   as senders of spam.

But well, if you aren't supposed to receive mail from South Korea, you could use this list. On my personal mail server all Chinese IPs are rejected with `550 Thank you for supporting Free Tibet.`, because I receive nothing but spam from China. (And that's not even close to the most rude example from my `check_sender_access` list.)

Comment: I have read postfix reference but don't understand that simple one sentence explanation. That's a specific question, based on the parameter listed in you answer, cannot reject spam mail as my question showed.

Comment: SPF is for that.

Comment: SPF make `ourcompany.com` is more trustable,does not help to reject spam mail from others.

Comment: It seems you haven't fully understood how SPF works. It really helps in that. It is designed for that.

Comment: I think there's something in postfix can check whether ip of `bill.gates@outlook.com` is `118.219.111.157` . If false,reject mail.But I don't know how to do it in postfix.

Comment: I know what's SPF, We cannot make all senders set SPF in their DNS.

Comment: Yes, but there's no other suitable test. Before SPF there simply weren't any. And the example used, `outlook.com`, does have an SPF record.

Comment: @ChrisKelly You can't make all senders set SPF, but you can correctly handle mail for domains that *do* set SPF.

Comment: Is there any postfix function can check whether ip of bill.gates@outlook.com is 118.219.111.157?If no,I don't think we can find a  perfect solution.

Comment: @ceejayoz: Check the edited last paragraph just for lulz. :)

Comment: The difference between `smtpd_recipient_restrictions` vs. `smtpd_sender_restrictions` is not what they are checking but when they do it. Because `MAIL FROM` comes always before `RCPT TO`, the checks performed after `RCPT TO` has most information about the envelope sender and recipient. I prefer it, among other things, because it makes it a lot easier to debug false positives from logs when you also know the supposed recipient.

Comment: It's called [delayed evaluation](http://www.postfix.org/SMTPD_ACCESS_README.html#timing). Delayed means that the directive specifies when to perform the checks listed. There are also different checks for clients, senders and recipients, and that's in the name of that check. Checks against client and sender can be performed delayed after we also know the recipient; benefits listed in the linked article.

Comment: @EsaJokinen,For those domains have no SPF record, will `policy-spf` process as 'fake' ?

Comment: Policy-spf only knows pass, softfail and hardfail. But spam filters may have independent scoring against no SPF at all.

Answer (score 1):

> Is there any postfix function can check whether ip of bill.gates@outlook.com is 118.219.111.157?If no,I don't think we can find a perfect solution.

That's precisely what SPF records do.

Via http://www.kitterman.com/spf/validate.html:

[image]

[image]

Comment: The ultimate solution for preventing 100% all spam from domains with clueless admins not implementing SPF, DKIM and DMARC would be rejecting all mail i.e. not maintaining a mail server at all.

Comment: Because you don't understand that email addresses don't have IPs, as well explained in my answer.

Comment: Did you read the answer? "as MX is for receiving mail rather than sending it." `MX` doesn't list sending MTAs, only receiving MTAs. That's why rejecting based on it will cause plenty of false positives. Even `outlook.com` itself sends mail from other IPs than its `MX` records. Which leads to the same conclusion: SPF is designed for what the ancient SMTP system itself fails to achieve.

Comment: @ChrisKelly Inbound and outbound email are frequently handled by entirely different sets of servers. StackOverflow's SPF record, for example, includes the outbound mail provider `sendgrid.net`, while inbound mail is handled by Google. A SPF record *can* include the `mx` instruction, which would tell you to allow the MX IPs as senders, but it's *optional* because it's not always what you want.

Answer (score 1):

You can also configure DMARC on your server, in addition to SPF, it will create an header like this :

```
Authentication-Results: name; dmarc=fail (p=reject dis=none) header.from=the_real_domain_that_some_phishing_mail_tries_to_imitate
```

When the policy of the domain is reject, then you can check for this header using header_checks parameter with pcre in postfix configuration file main.cf, in order to reject mail with this kind of header.

example :

```
header_checks pcre:/etc/postfix/header_checks
```

then in file /etc/postfix/header_checks :

```
/^Authentication-Results: [^;]+; dmarc=fail \(p=reject/ DISCARD optional text to store into the log like blocked
```

or if you want a bounce to the sender

```
/^Authentication-Results: [^;]+; dmarc=fail \(p=reject/ REJECT optional text to send with rejection
```

Personally I don't do that because still some ESP send untrusted mail according to DMARC, but that remain legitimate. I prefer the use of spamassassin rules, to keep the mail but store it directly to JUNK.

example of spamassassin rule :

```
header CUST_DMARC_FAIL_REJECT Authentication-Results =~ /dmarc=fail \(p=reject/
score CUST_DMARC_FAIL_REJECT 20.0
```